# PHP Adding Space to variable when using echo

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I'm performing a query on a MySQL Database using PHP and to check I was doing it right I echoed the SQL query. When doing this a space is added to the variable for some reason. Has anyone seen this before or know what causes this?

The code is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `rankings` WHERE `keyword` = '$keyword'";
echo $sql;
```

If I `echo $keyword` on it's own I get: keyword1

But when echoing the `$sql` variable I get:

```
SELECT * FROM `rankings` WHERE `keyword` = 'keyword1 '
```

So a space has been added to the end of keyword1.

Any ideas?

Comment: There may be a hidden character or something there. Is it preventing your query from working? Have you tried `trim($keyword)`?

Comment: I dont see any white space? could you clear it out ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard your edit got busted Sam. edit: oh, now it's back.

Comment: @Pabzoid, you need to check the formatting of you question.. Mark down is interfering and as you are quoting an echo, it is hard to know what your output is.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I fixed it. No further action required *Sam* ;-) enjoy your lunch.

Comment: can you please try `= '{$keyword}'";`

Comment: where and how is `$keyword` being defined? Plus, check your row, see if it does in fact contain a space and was entered during an insert. I'm next to 100% sure that's what's going on.

Comment: Heading for lunch in a bit *Ralph*. Thanks for the fix @Fred-ii-!

Comment: You're welcome *Sam!* - buon appetito mi amico, *ciao* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Hey Sam*, how was lunch? @JayBlanchard

Comment: @Fred-ii- just sat down to eat *Ralph*. Got delayed :-/

Comment: Seems like we scared another one off *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: Hi there! I've tried trim() and there isn't a hidden character. It isn't preventing my query from working strangely enough but I'm just not sure why it is happening.

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is a space, but you don't see it.
If you do `echo $keyword;`, you don't see whether there is a space.
Do it like this: `echo '"'.$keyword.'"';`.

Comment: that shouldn't matter and that's not what's causing the problem.  3/4 of your answer is a comment. *"Do it like this: `echo '"'.$keyword.'"';`"* - am sure it will reproduce the same thing.

Comment: Have a closer look @Pharaoh, this does not answer the question.

Comment: You're right; a comment would have been more fitting. How do you know that's not what's causing the problem?

Comment: ...It's in their db, am sure of it. That or how their variable is being taken from.

Comment: The code in the question is not yet connected to the db, there's only php variables. You mean `$keyword` is loaded from the database prior to this code?

Comment: that is unknown at this time. OP is not responding to any comments and I have voted to close as such.

Comment: It is loaded from the DB, however when echoing $keyword and when looking at the DB there is no space, it's only added when putting it in the quotation markings in the $sql variable as above!